# How to make Blazer use the application layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

[Blazer](https://github.com/ankane/blazer) uses its own layout so I loose the access of the application navbar and footer. I know that there is no official way to have it use a different one because I ask the owner of the Blazer. So what I'm asking is if anyone knows how to make the Blazer content appear on the `yield` of the application layout file?

I'll much appreciate. Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to extract Blazer layout to a separate file (please see [here](https://github.com/ankane/blazer/issues/50#issuecomment-234877705)) and use [`content_for`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-the-content-for-method) method to render your file within a named `yield`